# Sound effect on terminal open/close

Tags: sound

I have a question. I would like to know is there a way to have a small sound file play every time that I open a terminal window, and to have another small sound file play when I exit out of terminal. Im fairly noob-ish when it comes to Linux, so I apologize in advance if this question is noob-city lol.

--Sam Spade

Comment: Sounds events are implemented differently with different desktop environments. Some have more sound settings than others. First you need to tell which desktop environment are you using. Type `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`in terminal and report what this command prints out. Then maybe someone will be able to help you. Here you have some information: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363/how-to-integrate-sound-with-desktop-events

Comment: I am using GNOME 3.4.2

Comment: I've decided to run a script that opens terminal followed by playing a sound. Lol. Now, is there a way to make terminal play a specific sound everytime a command is completed successfully?